# With two restrictions on the parameters, how does an AR(p) process change as we increase p

Tags: time-series, variance, autoregressive

Suppose we have an AR(1) process with parameter $\theta$ such that $Z_i = \theta Z_{i-1} + \epsilon_i$

I wish to compare this to the general AR(p) process of the form

$Z_i = \theta_1 Z_{i-1} + \theta_2 Z_{i-2} + ... + \theta_p Z_{i-p} + \epsilon_i$

Keeping two restrictions on the parameters of the AR(1) and AR(p) processes.

Firstly, all parameters are strictly positive so that in both cases $Z_i$ can be thought of as an weighting of previous $Z_i$ (except that the weights don't sum to 1), without any negative parameters causing the graph to alternative signs.

Secondly, $\theta = \theta_1 + \theta_2 + ... + \theta_p$, that is the sum of the parameters in the AR(p) process is equal to the parameter of the AR(1) process.

**Without looking at the empirical autocovariance, and merely visually inspecting the series...**

My question is: Keeping these restrictions as we increase the number of parameters p, how does process change? Does the variance of the increments get smaller? Does the variance of $Z_i$ get smaller? Or is the variance unchanged?

Are there any noticable changes in the process as the number of parameters is increased?

Comment: Very nice question. Is this a homework or self-study exercise, though? If so, it should be tagged appropriately. Also, have you made any attempt to answer?

Comment: I was doing autoregressive work for homework, however this is just something I was interested in and wasn't asked about at all, unrelated to the questions. I tried to compare the variance of ar(1) and ar(2) using formulas online without being able to conclude much given the restrictions. I was hoping someone with more knowledge could provide some insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a partial answer for the case AR(1) vs. AR(2).

In the AR(1) case, the variance is (setting $\sigma^2=1$)
$$
\gamma_0=\frac{1}{1-\phi^2}
$$
In the AR(2) case, one may show that
$$
\gamma_0=\frac {(1-\phi_2)} {1-\phi_2-\phi_1^2 -\phi_1^2\phi_2 - \phi_2^2(1-\phi_2)} 
$$
This expression maybe helps motivate why I cannot come up with a general answer along this route, as the expressions for the variance will only become more complicated in the general AR(p) case.

Your restrictions imply that $0<\phi<1$ (restricting to the stationary case), $\phi_1,\phi_2>0$, $\phi_1+\phi_2=\phi$ and thus also $\phi>\phi_1$.

Mapping this to R for numerical evaluation gives me

```
phiAR1 <- seq(0.01,0.99,by=0.01)
phi_1 <- seq(0.01,0.99,by=0.01)

gamma0AR1 <- function(phiAR1) 1/(1-phiAR1^2)
gamma0AR2 <- function(phiAR1,phi_1){
  phi_2 <- phiAR1 - phi_1
  return(ifelse(phi_2>0,(1-phi_2)/(1-phi_2-phi_1^2 -phi_1^2*phi_2 - phi_2^2*(1-phi_2)),NA))
} 
Vardiff <- function(phiAR1,phi_1) gamma0AR1(phiAR1)-gamma0AR2(phiAR1,phi_1)
Vardiffs <- outer(phiAR1,phi_1,Vardiff)
persp(phiAR1,phi_1,Vardiffs)
min(Vardiffs[!is.na(Vardiffs)])
```

This seems to be a nonnegative function:

[image]

I also tried to let MAPLE verify this analytically via

```
restart;
assume(0<phi[AR1],phi[AR1]<1,phi[1]>0,phi[AR1]>phi[1]); 
is(1/(1-phi[AR1]^2) - (1-phi[2])/(1-phi[2]-(phi[1])^2 -(phi[1])^2*phi[2] - (phi[2])^2*(1-phi[2]))>0);
```

but that does not seem to a correct approach.