# Find the probability distribution of strictly stationary autoregressive process

Tags: time-series, distributions, stochastic-processes, autoregressive

Let $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a strictly stationary process. By definition, the one-dimensional marginal distribution is the same along the time:
$$X_t \sim D, \quad \forall t \geq 0.$$

Now, consider the following strictly stationary autoregressive process
$$X_t = 0.9 X_{t-1} + \eta_t, \quad \eta_t \stackrel{i.i.d.}{\sim} N(0,1).$$

Can I find $D$?

I may be making a mistake, but I don't know if what I'm going to do is correct:

$$D = 0.9 D + N(0,1).$$
So
$$0.1 D =  N(0,1).$$
So, $D = 10 N(0,1)$. Thus:
$$D = N(0,100)$$
Is this a Gaussian process?

Comment: $\mu$ is typically used to denote the expected value (e.g. of a Normal distribution), so it looks a bit weird to see it denoting a distribution. Some other symbol ($D$?) might make more intuitive sense.

Comment: It is a Gaussian process, but its variance is as given in e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235649/with-two-restrictions-on-the-parameters-how-does-an-arp-process-change-as-we/236558#236558

Comment: Thanks for the reference and the notation suggestions. Two questions, the first most important (i) Does this mean that the way I deduced the $D$ distribution is correct? (ii) Is it true that every strictly stationary process is Gaussian? Or just autoregressives that are strictly stationary?